# Mediapipe palm detection model outputs

Tags: c++, object-detection, mediapipe, tflite, palm

I want to add Mediapipe hand landmark detection to my C++ project, but mediapipe doesn't support CMake so I had to find another way,  I found that the hand landmark detection is a two-model run in serial.  the first model is palm detection and the second is landmark detection, from the mediapipe website I reached to the two models
the models are tflite models so adding them shouldn't be difficult
but I had a problem figuring out how to convert the palm output to bboxes, the model gives me two outputs one with shape (2016, 18) and a second (2016,)
the first one should be a

[number of anchors, 18]

0 - 4 are bounding box offset, width, and height: dx, dy, w ,h

4 - 18 are 7 hand keypoint x and y coordinates: x1,y1,x2,y2,...x7,y7

the second should be the accuracy for each bbox

(2016, 18)[0] –-> [-3896.9226   5079.4067   6987.4683   7181.9116 992.45654  4032.2664  -7006.974   -2635.5786  -4408.5684  -3171.507   -2381.8406  -3177.1763  -1996.8119  -2633.921 2559.212 5521.417 4017.0728   4059.862  ]

(2016,)[0] ---> -2090.7869

Could you please help me figure the needed math to end up with bbox?

During my research, I  found the same problem at https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3751
And in https://github.com/aashish2000/hand_tracking
But I couldn’t understand how to end up with bbox

Comment: I build a [dll](https://github.com/liuyulvv/mediapipe/tree/main/mediapipe/dll) of mediapipe, so mediapipe can be used with CMake. And I made a demo of  [face_mesh](https://github.com/liuyulvv/lvvi). If you think this is a solution, I can help you.

Comment: That's impreseve, I was trying a diffrent aproch but your way could work just fine.

Comment: I have a few questions about your demo, I'll write them in the "issues" section of lvvi repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main steps needed to convert the mediapipe palm models output to a rectangle are explained in this repo [terryky/tflite_gles_app.git](https://github.com/terryky/tflite_gles_app.git), they used the old models but the main steps are the same, in my repo, I made the necessary changes to run the new models both the palm model and the hand landmark detection you can found the source code here.[hand-landmarks-cpp.git](https://github.com/muhammedakyuzlu/hand-landmarks-cpp.git). I noticed that the python version runs at less 3X time faster than the CPP version probably because of the lag in TensorFlow C++ API -tflite- or maybe I have a bug in my code how knows:)